# PyroCMS module upgrade logic

Tags: php, pyrocms

I am working on v.5 my [PyroCMS poll module](https://github.com/vmichnowicz/polls). I am wondering about the best way to deal with users looking to upgrade from v.4 of the module. In the details.php file there is an upgrade method, however I don't think it ever gets called. Does this upgrade check have yet to be developed, or am I just totally missing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dang, you're right the upgrade code is not finished at all. This may well be a v1.1.0 change as so far only install/uninstall is using it. I'd just put a README or UPGRADE file in the root with some upgrade SQL.